# Eventlog entries for routing table changes

Tags: windows-event-log

someone knows if there´s a windows eventlog that informs routing table changes?

I´m trying to identify a problem with one machine that has a persistent route entry that shows everytime the windows initializes

Comment: Have you tried deleting the persistent route using the `delete -p` option?

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, no, Windows does not write an event to the event log when the routing table changes. You would need to write a script yourself that repeatedly stores the output and detects a change.

Like mentioned in the comments, I would attempt to delete the presumably persistent entry which should prevent it from coming back.